# Is default quota of GAE not big enough to run phoenix project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP and GAE. I'm trying to deploy elixir container of phoenix on GAE.

```
The requested amounnt of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas/ for more information on GCE resources
```

That error occurs when I deploy the container.
So I have checked the quotas of project with `gcloud` command, but there is no quotas which is exceeded.

```
quotas:
- limit: 1000.0
  metric: SNAPSHOTS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 5.0
  metric: NETWORKS
  usage: 1.0
- limit: 100.0
  metric: FIREWALLS
  usage: 6.0
- limit: 100.0
  metric: IMAGES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 8.0
  metric: STATIC_ADDRESSES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 200.0
  metric: ROUTES
  usage: 1.0
- limit: 15.0
  metric: FORWARDING_RULES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 50.0
  metric: TARGET_POOLS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 50.0
  metric: HEALTH_CHECKS
  usage: 2.0
- limit: 4.0
  metric: IN_USE_ADDRESSES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 50.0
  metric: TARGET_INSTANCES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: TARGET_HTTP_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: URL_MAPS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 5.0
  metric: BACKEND_SERVICES
  usage: 1.0
- limit: 100.0
  metric: INSTANCE_TEMPLATES
  usage: 1.0
- limit: 5.0
  metric: TARGET_VPN_GATEWAYS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: VPN_TUNNELS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 3.0
  metric: BACKEND_BUCKETS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: ROUTERS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: TARGET_SSL_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: TARGET_HTTPS_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: SSL_CERTIFICATES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 100.0
  metric: SUBNETWORKS
  usage: 24.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: TARGET_TCP_PROXIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 12.0
  metric: CPUS_ALL_REGIONS
  usage: 2.0
- limit: 0.0
  metric: SECURITY_POLICIES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 0.0
  metric: SECURITY_POLICY_RULES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 20.0
  metric: PACKET_MIRRORINGS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 100.0
  metric: NETWORK_ENDPOINT_GROUPS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 6.0
  metric: INTERCONNECTS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 5000.0
  metric: GLOBAL_INTERNAL_ADDRESSES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 5.0
  metric: VPN_GATEWAYS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 100.0
  metric: MACHINE_IMAGES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 0.0
  metric: SECURITY_POLICY_CEVAL_RULES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 0.0
  metric: GPUS_ALL_REGIONS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 5.0
  metric: EXTERNAL_VPN_GATEWAYS
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 1.0
  metric: PUBLIC_ADVERTISED_PREFIXES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 10.0
  metric: PUBLIC_DELEGATED_PREFIXES
  usage: 0.0
- limit: 128.0
  metric: STATIC_BYOIP_ADDRESSES
  usage: 0.0
```

I have no clue for resolving this problem. I and my coworker are wondering that the default quota of App engine is small, so it reaches quota limit with just 1 project.(It's not really though)
I even need a little hint. Help me!

Comment: As per [this community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-google-app-engine) it should be possible.  What is your app.yaml file? In what location is your App Engine application hosted (there could be some stock out issues on the specific region you are trying to deploy your app)? You can always set the [max_num_instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling) to a small value (e.g 3 or 2) and check if no quota is exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE uses Google Compute Engine's quota.

It looks like you've exceeded your GCE quota limit.

You can check GCE's VM instance quota limit at "Quota" page.

It is quota page which concludes GCE VM instance limit. ->
Quota Page for VM instance

[image: Quota Page for VM instance]

I think you configured number of instances over 8.

If you want to mitigate such limitation, Send request to Google via "EDIT QUOTAS".->
Send request

[image: Send request]